# Wifi in .Net application

Tags: asp.net, wifi

I am developing a **Web Application in ASP.Net(3.5)**. Now I am having a thought of integrating my applicaiton along with WiFi (i.e.) the **data from a mobile should be able to sent to the client system through WiFi**. Is it possible to do it ? If it can be done, tell me a solution to achieve this. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You would use standard communication methods (http/https/etc) over wifi, so yes, it's possible.

Comment: @ChrisBint, thanks for ur reply. I need some references and examples to work with it. Can you suggest me ....?

Comment: just look at standard web services. There is nothing different about implementing them over wifi as that is just the connectivity aspect. Plenty of examples on google, I would suggest starting there.

Comment: The application will just need access to the Internet, so whether this is WiFi or not is irrelevant, so I don't think there's a specific solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "client system"? You would like to write a mobile app which sends data to the server through WiFi, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application wouldn't be built specific to WiFi; you'd simply use network connections, and how the network connection is physically connected (or not) is irrelevant to your application.  Typically you'd make use of web service calls over https (or maybe http if the data isn't sensitive).  The OS takes care of the network connect itself, whether its Ethernet, WiFi, or cellular.

Comment: Yup, WiFi doesn't enter into it, it's either connected to the internet or not. That's all your app needs to know.